# Zsh weirdness regarding $SHLVL

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Can somebody explain the following behaviour, please?

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ zsh -c 'echo $SHLVL'
2
$ zsh -c '(echo $SHLVL)'
1
```

I don't understand last result. Does zsh reset $SHLVL for () subshells?
Bash result is different:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash -c 'echo $SHLVL'
2
$ bash -c '(echo $SHLVL)'
2
```

Which, at least, seems more logical.
In an case, I was expecting 3 for the last result when I tested this. Why no shell gives that result? What I am misunderstanding about $SHLVL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash the variable `SHLVL` is not incremented for subshells, see [abs guide](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/subshells.html#SUBSHNLEVREF). For nested subshells see `BASH_SUBSHELL`.

In zsh the doc says that `SHLVL` counts the number of shells, see [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-SHLVL), and that, surprise, `ZSH_SUBSHELL` counts nested subshells, see [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZSH_005fSUBSHELL-_003cS_003e).

To me, the decrementing effect of `SHLVL` in a zsh subshell is a bug; another possibility could be that `SHLVL` and `ZSH_SUBSHELL` might be added (an undocumented feature?).

```
$ zsh -c 'print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL ; (print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL)'
2 0
1 1
```

Comment: I think it's a bug, too. The adding hypothesis is interesting, though I deem it improbable. If we kept adding more subshell levels, then we'd need negative values for $SHLVL... (!?) I'll try to confirm it's a bug in zsh project itself. Thx for the detailed answer.

Comment: See this: `zsh -c '( ( (print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL) ) )'` echoes `-1 3`

Comment: Wow. Your hypothesis seems to be true, then. So, in zsh, one's real $SHLVL woud be $SHLVL + $ZSH_SUBSHELL, in fact. I have to think about how such a thing could be useful. At first sight, it seems weird, as it would break standard scripts depending on $SHLVL. Congrats, you seem to have discovered an undocumented feature!

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be fixed.

I'm running `zsh 5.7.1`:

```
❯ print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL
1 0
❯ (print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL)
1 1
❯ zsh -c 'print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL '        
2 0
❯ zsh -c '(print $SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL)'
2 1
```